# HTTP fetch request always fails on react-native

Tags: http, react-native, request, fetch

I have a backend on my server which doesn't have https configured. Before it worked fine with just http and everything was working. For some reason now I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
    at MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
```

I googled and it looks like the problem is http. It works fine with https on other apis. But mine doesn't have http configured. Is there a way to make it work with just http for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing on Android, you need to enable `clearTextTraffic` so the system allows your app to communicate through HTTP.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. With a hint of romin21, I made it working now. There's a file

#### android/app/src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml

that overwrites your AndroidManifest. So at first I tried adding it to AndroidManifest and of course it didn't work, I already had this file overwriting it. But when I added my backend's ip address to that file, it worked perfectly

```
<domain includeSubdomains="false">YOUR IP</domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution one is to add following code to `AndroidManifest.xml` File

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

But in my case I wanted to allow only my API domain So I have added following code to `android/app/src/res/xml/network-security-config.xml` file.

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">Your IP/Domain</domain>
    </domain-config>

</network-security-config>
```

I hope this is helpful. Thank you!